# For my class Library project in visual Studio 2013 ; Using post build event how do I copy the created dll to another path?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, dll, post-build

I have searched the net which has quite a few similar answers but they seem to differ with VS version. Each was differing so I though that I should ask you guys

So here is some detail.

i need to copy the dll at

> "C:\MyProjects\Visual Studio\Mylibrary Library\Mylibrary \Mylibrary \bin\Release\Mylibrary.dll"

to

> "C:\MyProjects\Unity\Projects\Valding\Valding\Assets\Classes\VadingClasses"

[image]

Comment: How about `copy "C:\MyProjects\Visual Studio\Mylibrary Library\Mylibrary \Mylibrary \bin\Release\Mylibrary.dll" "C:\MyProjects\Unity\Projects\Valding\Valding\Assets\Classes\VadingClasses"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post-build event, give the following `xcopy` a shot...

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\Mylibrary.dll" "C:\MyProjects\Unity\Projects\Valding\Valding\Assets\Classes\VadingClasses" /Y
```

Here are some common switches used with [xcopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx), as well as the command syntax

```
xcopy "your-source-path" "your-destination-path"
```

- `/I` - treat as a directory if copying multiple files
- `/Q` - Do not display the files being copied.
- `/S` - Copy subdirectories unless empty.
- `/E` - Copy empty subdirectories.
- `/Y` - Do not prompt for overwrite of existing files.
- `/R` - Overwrite read only files.

---

Note that `copy` should work as well for you as well in this case, but `xcopy` should afford you some benefit if you wish to copy more than just a single file at some point. Check out these various further reading resources:

- [Pre-build Event/Post-build Event Command Line Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx) - available macros you may wish to leverage e.g. `$(ProjectDir)`
- [COPY, XCOPY and ROBOCOPY Command Lines](http://www.xtraficient.com/batch-files/copy-and-rename-files) - explanation regarding similarities/differences

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot!
I hope that this helps others too.